inject transient service that injects other transient services
I'm running into a situation where I can't seem to use transient service that injects other transient services. For example, suppose I have a services that looks like this:
@Injectable()
export class ParentService {
   private child1 = inject(ChildService1);
   private child2 = inject(ChildService2);
   // ... more injects
}

@Injectable()
export class ChildService1 {
   private subChild1 = inject(SubChildService1);
   // ... more injects
}

@Injectable()
export class ChildService2 {
   private subChild2 = inject(SubChildService2);
   // ... more injects
}

@Injectable()
export class SubChildService1 {
}

@Injectable()
export class SubChildService2 {
}

Now, I would like to use ParentService in my component like this:
@Component({  
providers: [ParentService]
})
export class MyComponent {
   private parentService = inject(ParentService);
}

If I don't list all my services, including services that ParentService depends on, in providers array, I get NullInjectionError. The problem is that I could have lots of services injected in ParentService that also inject other transient sub services. How can I just use transient ParentService without listing all dependencies in providers array?

usually the best way to mark every service @Injectable({provideIn: 'root'}) so you have a singleton for the whole app. If you mark all of your services like this(and remove them from providers arrays) they will be provided in the root injector automatically and the problem will be gone. I would say you should use providers array only in the rare cases and only if you know what you are doing

If I use provideIn: root, it will create singleton, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I need my services to be transient. I can create several instances of MyComponent class with MyComponent holding separate instance of ParentService service.

currently there is no way to make a "provider" with auto creating more "providers". the best thing you could do I am afraid is to export array of everything you need to provide export PARENT_SERVICE_PROVIDERS = [ParentService, Child1Service, Child2Service, ....];

Or it can be formed as a function so even some config can be passed.
export function provideParentService(config: ParentConfig) {return [....]} 

I think the main issue here is how to use and Injector to get a transient instance. If you specify a provider that isn't marked as providedIn: 'root in a standalone Component, it will be transient. How do we repeat that behavior with inject or Injector.get?

You would have to use NgModule. Then you can have all transient dependencies provided in that module. After that you will only have to import that single NgModule.
